# fullpage.js scrollOverflow doesn't work,I can't slide down the section at all

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fullpage.js

The scrollOverflow attribute does not work properly in my project,there is no scrollbar when the content is overflowed, so I write a easy sample to figure out the problem.
The problem is that When I check this on my Browser,No matter click or scroll,it doesn't work,I can only see the first section.
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>无标题文档</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.1/jquery.fullPage.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.1/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.7/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
            $('#dowebok').fullpage({         
                <!--loopHorizontal: false,-->
                navigation: true,
                css3:true,
                scrollOverflow: true
                })
      })
</script>
<div id="dowebok">
   <div class="section">section1</div>
   <div class="section">section2</div>
   <div class="section">section3</div>
   <div class="section">
   section4

    ...........
(contents which runs really long, larger than the size of the section)   

   </div>
   </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the fullpage.js version 2.8.1.

I tried your code using a v2.7.7 fullpage.js file and it worked fine. I would have commented this but I don't have enough privilege.

Edit: The problem doesn't seem to be with fullpage.js, because you need to load scrolloverflow.js before loading fullpage.js as mentioned in the fullpage.js Docs.

Comment: Thank you very much~and it also worked well in my real project.

Comment: As you can see it is working properly [on the demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) using 2.8.1. If you have some trouble it might be due to [this known issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2048), which can easily be solved by not using float:left or right.

Comment: But i didn't link any CSS stylesheet in the above-cited code, except for jquery.fullPage.css

Comment: @Z-Jenny unless you provide a reproduction of your problem in jsfiddle or codepen we can not be sure what your problem is. But it seems to  be in your side and not in fullpage.js anyways.

Comment: @Alvaro I'm sure the problem is with fullpage.js. See my edited answer for the reproduction of the bug. The reproduction doesn't use CSS or JS except for the script needed to launch fullpage.js.

Comment: @ParagAgarwal I'm afraid to tell you the problem is in your side :) fullpage.js 2.8.1. doesn't use slimScroll,which you are loading. It uses scrolloverflow.js which is a fork of iScroll.js. **And** as stated in the docs it should be included before fullpage.js.

Comment: @Alvaro  I see~seems like the translated version I checked and some video tutorial  in my country haven't been updated.I should have checked the official docs on github.Thanks~